# Query across multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following classes:

```
class School
  belongs_to :zipcode
end

class Zipcode
  has_many :schools
  belongs_to :city
end

class City
  has_many :zipcodes
  belongs_to :county
end

class County
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :state
end

class State
  has_many :counties
end
```

Given a state id, how do I find all the schools located within said state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a long `joins` with a `where` clause like this

```
School.joins(zipcode: { city: { county: :state } }).where(states: { id: <STATE_ID> })
```

Comment: I get the following error:   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'states.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: What are you passing to the method to identify the state? A state name (e.g. "NY") or an ID (e.g. 1)?

Comment: just an ID, my where clause looks like this .where(states: { id: 3 })

Comment: `states` in the where clause should be `where(state: { id: <state_id> })`

Comment: Hmm in my experience, it should be the pluralized table name (e.g. `states`), but @Dobabeswe does CDub's suggestion work for you?

Comment: No. Neither one works. Still get the same error message.

Comment: Can you verify your DB schema.. Is State#id a valid attribute and a valid column? I assume everything is setup properly in the migration and with ActiveRecord?

Comment: It is now working.  I had a namespace problem.  You are correct @carlosramireziii, the table name should be pluralized.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution. If you are using Rails 3.1 or higher, you can try nested `has_many :through`

```
class School
  belongs_to :zipcode
end

class Zipcode
  has_many :schools
  belongs_to :city
end

class City
  has_many :zipcodes
  has_many :schools, :through => :zipcodes
  belongs_to :county
end

class County
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :schools, :through => :cities
end

class State
  has_many :counties
  has_many :schools, :through => :counties
end
```

Now you can just say

```
State.find(<id>).schools
```

Which internally fires this query

> SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" INNER JOIN
>   "zipcodes" ON "schools"."zipcode_id" = "zipcodes"."id" INNER JOIN
>   "cities" ON "zipcodes"."city_id" = "cities"."id" INNER JOIN "counties"
>   ON "cities"."county_id" = "counties"."id" WHERE "counties"."state_id"
>   = 1

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `joins`... Something like:

```
School.joins(zipcode: { city: { county: :state } }).where("state.id" => <state_id>)
```

Comment: In this case, the associations need to be nested since they are not all associations of the `School` model itself. The snippet as written will result in an error.

Comment: Good call @carlosramireziii - I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make a scope to make things easier if you're doing this query a lot. Something:

```
scope :where_state_is, ->(state_name) { joins(:zipcode, :city, :county, :state).where("state.name = ?", state_name ) } 

School.where_state_is('NY')
```

Comment: Maybe try `joins(:zipcode => {:city => { :county => :state }})` instead?